# How to detect touch screen in windows 8.1 on internet explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to detect touch screen in windows 8.1 specially on IE 10/11 as per my project requirement...

I have tried with Modernizer.touch but its getting false on IE (touch screen).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `navigator` ?

```
function is_touch_device() {
 return (('ontouchstart' in window)
      || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)
      || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));
}

if (is_touch_device()) {
   alert("Yay! Its touch");
}else{
   alert("Not touch!") 
}
```

Full source:http://ctrlq.org/code/19616-detect-touch-screen-javascript